# for Loop Not Running - Temperature Problem

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

I'm having some trouble with this simple for loop using user inputs question. The problem wants me to create a table that converts fahrenheit to celcius, taking user input values for the starting, ending, and increment values for the table using scanf. I've only been coding for 2 weeks, and I just started loops, but this seems like it should work. Thanks! Here is the code I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>



int main (void) 
{
    int f, c, f_min, f_max, i;

    printf("Enter the minimum (starting) temperature value: ");
    scanf("%d", &f_min);

    printf("Enter the maximum (ending) temperature value: ");
    scanf("%d", &f_max);

    printf("Enter the table increment value: ");
    scanf("%d", &i);

    for (f = scanf("%d", &f_min); f <= scanf("%d", &f_max); f = f + scanf("%d", &i))
    {
        c = ((f - 32.0) * (5.0 / 9.0));
        // printf("Degrees in C is: %d");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When I run the code, it correctly prompts and scans the 3 values, but then the for loop won't run and the terminal just sits empty.

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for debugging tips. And read the documentation for `scanf()`.

Comment: Why are you using `scanf` again inside your for loop condition?

Comment: Why are you `scanf()`ing again in the `for` loop?? You already got those values. But now you ask it to input them again for every iteration (well, `f_min` only on the first). I vote to close as a typo.

Comment: The votes to close as a "typo" are wrong - OP has a conceptual error, not a mechanical one

Comment: Just as a side note: It is unsafe to use `scanf` without checking the return value. See this page for further information: [A beginners' guide away from scanf()](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html)

Answer (score 5):

You are calling `scanf` inside your loop initializer, loop guard, and loop increment count, which means that the program is waiting for input from you at the beginning of the loop, at the beginning of each loop iteration, then at the end of each loop iteration. You also aren't comparing the values `f_max` and `i` but the return value of `scanf`, which is the number of format specifiers it successfully populated from the input string, not the values read.

You already have the values you want, `f_min`, `f_max` and `i`, just use those in the loop:

```
for(f = f_min; f <= f_max; f+=i)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! The reason I used scanf in my for loop was because I already did: for(f = f_min; f <= f_max; f+=i) and it did not run in my terminal. When I executed the code for this, my program quit after the printf/scanf statements. Did it work on your end when you compiled it? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
    for (f = scanf("%d", &f_min); f <= scanf("%d", &f_max); f = f + scanf("%d", &i))
```

Each time you call `scanf()` it will wait for input from you. This is why the for loop appears to not run. In addition, `scanf()` returns a code that indicates a success or error of the operation. I think this isn't what you want. You have already read the min, max, and increment values into variables, so you don't need `scanf()` here at all. Just use the variables:

```
for (f = f_min; f <= f_max; f += i)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! The reason I used scanf in my for loop was because I already did: for(f = f_min; f <= f_max; f+=i) and it did not run in my terminal. When I executed the code for this, my program quit after the printf/scanf statements. Did it work on your end when you compiled it? Thanks!

Comment: @The_Bandit I suggest that you learn what different constructs actually do and reason logically about how to use them to accomplish the goal you want rather than just guessing what you want. Here you definitely do NOT need `scanf()` in the for loop because it will keep pausing to get input which isn't what you want. If you have problems with different code than posted in your original answer, you need to post a new question with your current code. We can help you from there.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` returns the number of input items successfully converted and assigned, or `EOF` if it sees an end of file or error indication on the input stream.  It does not return the entered value.

You don't need to *read* a new value for each `f` - you just set it to `f_min` and then increment it until it's greater than `f_max`:

```
for ( f = f_min; f <= f_max; f += i )
  ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! The reason I used scanf in my for loop was because I already did: for(f = f_min; f <= f_max; f+=i) and it did not run in my terminal. When I executed the code for this, my program quit after the printf/scanf statements. Did it work on your end when you compiled it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in one of the answer `scanf` returns number of iteams it reads. 
For example `A = scanf("%d, %d", &f1, &f2);`. In this case A will be 2 since the `scanf` read two values. 
 
In your code:

```
for (f = scanf("%d", &f_min); f <= scanf("%d", &f_max); f = f + scanf("%d", &i))
```

Here: 
`f = scanf("%d", &f_min)` will be evaluated as `1` and value of `f` will also become `1`

& `f <= scanf("%d", &f_max)` will be evaluated as `f <= 1`. Since value of f is 1 this statement will be true.

&  `f = f + scanf("%d", &i)` will be evaluated as `f = f + 1`.

In all the above cases I assumed as you have provided inputs to `scanf` and since it is reading single integer it will return `1`

So your for will become:

```
for (f = 1; f <= 1; f = f + 1)
```

Which will be evaluated exactly once.

What happens when you don't provide any input to the scanf? it will be:

```
    for (f = 0; f <= 0; f = f + 0)
    {
    }
```